Can I safely remove this column between the two closets?
A couple of pictures:

Outside
[]
The first picture shows a center column in the middle of one large closet.  I would like to remove the two double 2x10 headers and replace it with one double 2x10 header that would span both openings (about 10 feet). At that point I would remove the column.
The second picture shows that the joists above meet at the back wall of the closet, not the wall I would be working on. Is it safe to remove the two existing headers without any additional supports and replace them with one spanning the opening?

It looks like the back wall is the load bearing wall.  The front wall seems like just an overbuilt wall, but do not know what is above those walls, which makes this not a yes/no question.  Extra weight above and/or a support wall below will make this a no.  Should have a building expert(contractor, inspector, engineer) see and check.  They might see something your pictures are not showing us.

Thanks for the reply.  It is in the basement so there is nothing below except the slab.  As far as "above" there is only floor, not walls.  Does that make a difference?

Yes it should be safe.  Most closet walls are usually not load bearing, but there is always the odd one.  The back wall is load bearing and do need an expert if ever going to change it.

You need to do some more poking around.   If there was a post between the doors holding up those beam-like pieces above the doors, I would expect them to extend over the post, not end just shy of it.  But what in fact are those pieces above the doors? I would want to know.

When I put my hand down in the column it seems like it is hollow in there.
